# do we need to compare each element of a array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code:

```
int isUsed[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

How to compare if all of the elements in this array are equal to 1? or other value?
I know we can loop the array and compare it one by one, but do we have other ways to do it?

Comment: Answer is NO.Not possible without accessing each element.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the way which you know exists, i.e. loop the array and compare elements one by one? Do you feel it is suboptimal? If so, why?

Comment: yes, I feel it is better if we have a c library method

Comment: @user2131316: to have library methods for every requirement of this complexity would add up to a lot of functions, any one of which wouldn't be used that often. I'd rather they added library functions that made it easy to do something that's currently difficult to code yourself. (If you want this kind of convenience C++ has Standard library functions....)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you must do it element by element.

If your array consists of just pure integer types (i.e. not an array of `struct`s) and you just want to check for equality, you can use [`memcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp).

This of course loops internally, but it's a pre-made standard function so it aids readability. It *might* hurt performance though, since it compares `char`s. On the other hand (after comments) it might gain performance due to being a well-known library function which might be optimized.

Also, for completeness', the reason I had the caveat about no `struct`s above is that structures often contain pad bytes, which will be "seen" by `memcmp()` and can cause an incorrect result.

For instance:

```
struct {
  int x;
  char y;
  int z;
} a = { 1, 2, 3 }, b = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

On many systems, the above `struct` will have padding between `y` and `z`, which might cause an incorrect result from `memcmp()` since the padding bytes have undefined values.

Comment: *It might hurt performance*? Even after loop unroll or even a special machine instruction supports?

Comment: @johnchen902 why hurt performance? `memcmp()` is good suggestion.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It's the answer that said it hurt performance. I am questioning unwind too.

Comment: @johnchen902 For e.g. `int x[100], y[100];`, `memcmp()` must do 400 byte-sized comparisons (assuming `sizeof (int) == 4`). An application loop comparing `int`s only needs 100, which might make a difference. And I said *might*.

Comment: @unwind I can't give your second like for your comment. nice thanks!

Comment: for structures we can use `==` for example `a == b`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No, we cannot. There is no `==` operator for structures in C. Assignment (`=`) yes, but no comparison.

Comment: @unwind Ooh! I am wrong and you are correct I confused due to `=`, `==` is not valid for structs

Comment: @unwind memcmp **does not** do 400 byte comparisons. Look into the source of good libraries. It will use the word size of the machine, e.g. 64bit, for comparisons. And it will do QWORD-aligned memory access. You can't usually beat that in a simple loop.

Answer (score 4):

For primitive data types (not structs), if you know the size of the array and what you are trying to compare against: `memcmp`will do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int allOnes[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

   int isUsed[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};

   if( memcmp( isUsed, allOnes, sizeof allOnes ) == 0 )
       printf( "Array has only 1's\n" );
   else
       printf( "At least one element is not 1\n" );
}
```

---

EDIT: about performance...

Some comments mention the performance of `memcmp` and loops, including unrolled loops.

Below is a simple test program to measure performance. In my machine (Mac OS X, LLVM compiler), this is what I get:

```
memcmp: 0.036031 seconds result=1
loop: 0.097180 seconds result=1
unrolled loop: 0.075623 seconds result=1
```

Before making specific comments about the numbers above, please note that:

- I'm not making a generic claim, just showing that in my environment the `memcmp` solution beats the other ones by a large margin.
- the loop unrolling I have is not the greatest implementation. It's just a crude attempt to have some number for loop unrolling in place.

Feel free to rework the code and post other numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static int allOnes[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};

bool compareWithMemcmp()
{
       int isUsed[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
       return memcmp( isUsed, allOnes, sizeof allOnes ) == 0;
}

bool compareWithLoop()
{
       int isUsed[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
       for( int i = 0; i < sizeof allOnes / sizeof allOnes[0]; i++)
           if( isUsed[i] != 1 )
               return false;
       return true;
}

bool compareWithUnrolledLoop()
{
       int isUsed[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
       // IMPORTANT: doesn't account for odd-length array
       for( int i = 0; i < sizeof allOnes / sizeof allOnes[0]; i += 2)
           if( (isUsed[i] != 1) || (isUsed[i+1] != 1) )
               return false;
       return true;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    bool result;

    clock_t begin = clock();
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
       result = compareWithMemcmp();
    printf( "memcmp: %f seconds result=%d\n",
            (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, result );

    begin = clock();
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
       result = compareWithLoop();
    printf( "loop: %f seconds result=%d\n",
            (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, result );

    begin = clock();
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
       result = compareWithUnrolledLoop();
    printf( "unrolled loop: %f seconds result=%d\n",
            (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, result );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare the array elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than comparing each element at a time. Though it slows you down, but there is no alternative. Try

```
#define NULL (void*)0
memcmp(char* source, const char * dest, int count);
```

returns  NULL if String matches.

Comment: your answer is duplicate of Unwind's answer, And `String` is **wrong** in your words.

Comment: unwind : didn't see your msg frnd, true if null is defined as #define NULL (void*)0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use assembly inline , take from this example :

you can write a macro to repeat this code 6 times, about your issue :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int64_t isUsed[ 1 ] = { 1 };

int main ( void )
{

 __asm__
(
    "\n movq  %[a] , %%rax"
    "\n cmpq  $1 , %%rax"
    :
    : [ a ] "m" ( isUsed[0] )
);

__asm__ goto ("jne %l0\n"
: 
: 
: 
: NotEqual);


printf ("\n Array Contains 1 in all elements");
return 1 ;

NotEqual:

printf ("\n Array Not contains 1 in all elements");

return 0 ;
}
```

this is the assembly code : (small)

```
 movq  isUsed(%rip) , %rax
 cmpq  $1 , %rax
 jne .L2
```

beware of integer types that you will use ( int32_t or int64_t : inttypes.h )

Comment: You can, but chances are overwhelming your code will be slower than what the compiler would produce if you cranked up he optimization level. Playing with assembly is fun and beating the compiler is possible - but unless your name is Agner Fog (or someone equally exceptional) the chances are you won't.

Comment: @NikBougalis, but how would you ever get a cool name like Agner Fog if you didn't try to beat the compiler...?

Comment: @gradyplayer that's a fair point - there's nothing wrong with trying. I did say it was fun playing with assembly ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can you gcc extension :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define VECTOR_SIZE         4
typedef int v4int __attribute__ ((vector_size(sizeof(int32_t)*VECTOR_SIZE))); 


typedef union f4vector   
{
 v4int       v;
 __int128_t   value ;
} f4vector;



int main()
{
union f4vector a, b, c;

a.v = (v4int) { 1, 1, 1, 2 }; // your vector
b.v = (v4int) { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

c.v = a.v - b.v;

if ( c.value == 0 )
    puts ( "array contains all 1");
else
    puts ("array Not contais all 1");

return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't go along with any answer that says there's no other way...

The answer depends on how the array might be changed.

Given an array which you've pre-set to some known value, and no futher changes, the test is trivial, and the solution is O(1).  It is all `1` because you made it so.

Once you start changing the values, if there is some pattern to the way in which they're changed then you might be able to record information on that pattern itself and the test could be made against history in less than O(n).

For example, when you alter one element in the array, you might set a flag elsewhere indicating which parts of the array need reevaluation.  If all of the alterations are clustered in a small area then you may need to test only a small part of the array.

However, in the specific example given, a small array of `isUsed[]`, it might be reasonable to assume that each element has only two possible states.  If you used a bit-mask for that, then testing the whole array might be a single integer operation.  It does visit every element implicitly, but it's much more efficient than a loop.